# How can I ensure everything is removed when I delete an account from Opera 10?

Tags: email, opera, privacy, opera-mail

I am using Opera 10. I have added my Gmail account to it. Today I have deleted the account from 'Tools -> Mail and Chat accounts'. Now I want to ensure that all messages together with other relevant stored data are deleted from my Hard Drive. Please guide me to check this thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're using windows, you can go to c:\users\username\appdata\local\opera\opera\mail

that's where it stores everything.  If you have no other mail accounts, you can delecte the whole folder, otherwise, you'll have to look inside to see which one to delete.